# Checking SQL Configuration in Backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to diagnose an issue with SQL Server 2016 that occurred after some software was updated and I wanted to see if any of the server configurations changed. I have a backup of the master db and I figured I could compare settings between the live master and the backup. I read that "network packet size (B)" could cause "Protocol error in TDS stream" and I know how to look up the configuration using sp_configure but how can I look it up in the "master" backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is to copy regularly some views from master database (in fact mssqlsystemresources db) into a newly designed database and compare it.
Everytime you will query sys.configurations, the data will be retrieved from the actual system database...